# Blender suddenly keeps crashing after re-path library folder of the gaffer HDRI's

Tags: add-on

newbie here can someone please help me.. Blender keeps crashing after the addon gaffer was looking for my HDRi's folder.. now when I try to open my files and just start up blender it starts to crash..

here is my crash log.

````
=====================================
= Blender 2.93.5 System Information =
=====================================


Blender:
=====================================

version: 2.93.5, branch: master, commit date: 2021-10-05 12:04, hash: a791bdabd0b2, type: release
build date: 2021-10-06, 06:44:49
platform: Windows
binary path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\blender.exe'
build cflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /nologo /J /Gd /MP /bigobj -openmp   
build cxxflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /EHsc /nologo /J /Gd /MP /EHsc /bigobj /permissive- /Zc:twoPhase- -openmp /std:c++17 /Zc:__cplusplus   
build linkflags: /MACHINE:X64  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /STACK:2097152 /ignore:4049 /ignore:4217 /ignore:4221
build system: CMake

Python:
=====================================

version: 3.9.2 (default, Mar  1 2021, 08:18:55) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
file system encoding: utf-8:surrogatepass
paths:
    'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\scripts\\startup'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts\\startup'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\python39.zip'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\python\\DLLs'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\python\\lib'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\python\\bin'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\python'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\python\\lib\\site-packages'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts\\freestyle\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts\\addons\\modules'
    'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\scripts\\addons\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts\\addons'
    'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\scripts\\addons'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts\\addons_contrib'

Python (External Binary):
=====================================

binary path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\python\\bin\\python.EXE'
version: Python 3.9.2

Directories:
=====================================

scripts:
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 2.93\\2.93\\scripts'
    'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\scripts'
user scripts: 'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\scripts'
pref scripts: None
datafiles: 'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\datafiles'
config: 'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\config'
scripts : 'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\scripts'
autosave: 'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\autosave'
tempdir: 'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\blender_a29976\\'

FFmpeg:
=====================================

avcodec:   '58, 54, 100'
avdevice:  '58,  8, 100'
avformat:  '58, 29, 100'
avutil:    '56, 31, 100'
swscale:   ' 5,  5, 100'

SDL:
=====================================

Version: 2.0.12
Loading method: linked (WITH_SDL_DYNLOAD=OFF)

Other Libraries:
=====================================

OpenColorIO:  2,  0,  0
OpenImageIO:  2,  1, 15
OpenShadingLanguage:  1, 11, 10
OpenSubdiv:  0,  0,  0
OpenVDB:  8,  0,  0
Alembic:  1,  7, 16
USD:  0, 21,  2

OpenGL:
=====================================

renderer:   'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2'
vendor:     'NVIDIA Corporation'
version:    '4.5.0 NVIDIA 472.12'
extensions:
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays
    GL_ARB_base_instance
    GL_ARB_bindless_texture
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_clear_texture
    GL_ARB_clip_control
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage
    GL_ARB_compute_shader
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer
    GL_ARB_copy_image
    GL_ARB_cull_distance
    GL_ARB_debug_output
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp
    GL_ARB_depth_texture
    GL_ARB_derivative_control
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced
    GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions
    GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport
    GL_ARB_fragment_program
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader_interlock
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
    GL_ARB_geometry_shader4
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image
    GL_ARB_gl_spirv
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex
    GL_ARB_imaging
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_multi_bind
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_multisample
    GL_ARB_multitexture
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2
    GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile
    GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_point_parameters
    GL_ARB_point_sprite
    GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp
    GL_ARB_post_depth_coverage
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior
    GL_ARB_robustness
    GL_ARB_sample_locations
    GL_ARB_sample_shading
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map
    GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters
    GL_ARB_shader_ballot
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding
    GL_ARB_shader_clock
    GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters
    GL_ARB_shader_group_vote
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store
    GL_ARB_shader_image_size
    GL_ARB_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_precision
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod
    GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing
    GL_ARB_shadow
    GL_ARB_sparse_buffer
    GL_ARB_sparse_texture
    GL_ARB_sparse_texture2
    GL_ARB_sparse_texture_clamp
    GL_ARB_spirv_extensions
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing
    GL_ARB_sync
    GL_ARB_tessellation_shader
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_texture_compression
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_minmax
    GL_ARB_texture_float
    GL_ARB_texture_gather
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle
    GL_ARB_texture_rg
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui
    GL_ARB_texture_stencil8
    GL_ARB_texture_storage
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle
    GL_ARB_texture_view
    GL_ARB_timer_query
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_program
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev
    GL_ARB_viewport_array
    GL_ARB_window_pos
    GL_ATI_draw_buffers
    GL_ATI_texture_float
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once
    GL_EXTX_framebuffer_mixed_formats
    GL_EXT_Cg_shader
    GL_EXT_abgr
    GL_EXT_bgra
    GL_EXT_bindable_uniform
    GL_EXT_blend_color
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax
    GL_EXT_blend_subtract
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array
    GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test
    GL_EXT_direct_state_access
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements
    GL_EXT_fog_coord
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader4
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4
    GL_EXT_import_sync_object
    GL_EXT_memory_object
    GL_EXT_memory_object_win32
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
    GL_EXT_multiview_texture_multisample
    GL_EXT_multiview_timer_query
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_EXT_packed_float
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_EXT_point_parameters
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp
    GL_EXT_post_depth_coverage
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex
    GL_EXT_raster_multisample
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal
    GL_EXT_secondary_color
    GL_EXT_semaphore
    GL_EXT_semaphore_win32
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color
    GL_EXT_shader_image_load_formatted
    GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs
    GL_EXT_sparse_texture2
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
    GL_EXT_texture3D
    GL_EXT_texture_array
    GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_minmax
    GL_EXT_texture_integer
    GL_EXT_texture_lod
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp
    GL_EXT_texture_object
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
    GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent
    GL_EXT_texture_storage
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle
    GL_EXT_timer_query
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback2
    GL_EXT_vertex_array
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit
    GL_EXT_win32_keyed_mutex
    GL_EXT_window_rectangles
    GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control
    GL_KHR_debug
    GL_KHR_no_error
    GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile
    GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior
    GL_KHR_robustness
    GL_KHR_shader_subgroup
    GL_KTX_buffer_region
    GL_NVX_blend_equation_advanced_multi_draw_buffers
    GL_NVX_conditional_render
    GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info
    GL_NVX_gpu_multicast2
    GL_NVX_linked_gpu_multicast
    GL_NVX_multigpu_info
    GL_NVX_nvenc_interop
    GL_NVX_progress_fence
    GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility
    GL_NV_ES3_1_compatibility
    GL_NV_alpha_to_coverage_dither_control
    GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect_count
    GL_NV_bindless_texture
    GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced
    GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
    GL_NV_blend_minmax_factor
    GL_NV_blend_square
    GL_NV_clip_space_w_scaling
    GL_NV_command_list
    GL_NV_compute_program5
    GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives
    GL_NV_conditional_render
    GL_NV_conservative_raster
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_dilate
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_pre_snap
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_pre_snap_triangles
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_underestimation
    GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color
    GL_NV_copy_image
    GL_NV_depth_buffer_float
    GL_NV_depth_clamp
    GL_NV_draw_texture
    GL_NV_draw_vulkan_image
    GL_NV_explicit_multisample
    GL_NV_feature_query
    GL_NV_fence
    GL_NV_fill_rectangle
    GL_NV_float_buffer
    GL_NV_fog_distance
    GL_NV_fragment_coverage_to_color
    GL_NV_fragment_program
    GL_NV_fragment_program2
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option
    GL_NV_fragment_shader_barycentric
    GL_NV_fragment_shader_interlock
    GL_NV_framebuffer_mixed_samples
    GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage
    GL_NV_geometry_shader4
    GL_NV_geometry_shader_passthrough
    GL_NV_gpu_multicast
    GL_NV_gpu_program4
    GL_NV_gpu_program4_1
    GL_NV_gpu_program5
    GL_NV_gpu_program5_mem_extended
    GL_NV_gpu_program_fp64
    GL_NV_gpu_shader5
    GL_NV_half_float
    GL_NV_internalformat_sample_query
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent
    GL_NV_memory_attachment
    GL_NV_memory_object_sparse
    GL_NV_mesh_shader
    GL_NV_multisample_coverage
    GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint
    GL_NV_occlusion_query
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2
    GL_NV_path_rendering
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge
    GL_NV_pixel_data_range
    GL_NV_point_sprite
    GL_NV_primitive_restart
    GL_NV_query_resource
    GL_NV_query_resource_tag
    GL_NV_register_combiners
    GL_NV_register_combiners2
    GL_NV_representative_fragment_test
    GL_NV_sample_locations
    GL_NV_sample_mask_override_coverage
    GL_NV_scissor_exclusive
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_counters
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_float
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_float64
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_fp16_vector
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_int64
    GL_NV_shader_buffer_load
    GL_NV_shader_storage_buffer_object
    GL_NV_shader_subgroup_partitioned
    GL_NV_shader_texture_footprint
    GL_NV_shader_thread_group
    GL_NV_shader_thread_shuffle
    GL_NV_shading_rate_image
    GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection
    GL_NV_texture_barrier
    GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4
    GL_NV_texture_multisample
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle_compressed
    GL_NV_texture_shader
    GL_NV_texture_shader2
    GL_NV_texture_shader3
    GL_NV_timeline_semaphore
    GL_NV_transform_feedback
    GL_NV_transform_feedback2
    GL_NV_uniform_buffer_unified_memory
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range2
    GL_NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit
    GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory
    GL_NV_vertex_program
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1
    GL_NV_vertex_program2
    GL_NV_vertex_program2_option
    GL_NV_vertex_program3
    GL_NV_viewport_array2
    GL_NV_viewport_swizzle
    GL_OVR_multiview
    GL_OVR_multiview2
    GL_S3_s3tc
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod
    GL_SGIX_depth_texture
    GL_SGIX_shadow
    GL_SUN_slice_accum
    GL_WIN_swap_hint
    WGL_EXT_swap_control

Implementation Dependent OpenGL Limits:
=====================================

Maximum DrawElements Vertices:  1048576
Maximum DrawElements Indices:   1048576

GLSL:
Maximum Varying Floats: 124
Maximum Vertex Attributes:  16
Maximum Vertex Uniform Components:  4096
Maximum Fragment Uniform Components:    4096
Maximum Vertex Image Units: 32
Maximum Fragment Image Units:   32
Maximum Pipeline Image Units:   192

Cycles:
=====================================


CPU device capabilities: SSE2 SSE3 SSE41 AVX AVX2

OpenCL device capabilities:
Number of platforms: 1
Platform #0
    Platform Name: NVIDIA CUDA
    Platform Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
    Platform Version: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 11.4.136
    Platform Profile: FULL_PROFILE
    Platform Extensions: cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_device_uuid cl_khr_pci_bus_info
    Number of devices: 1
        Device: #0
            Device Name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER
            Device Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
            Device OpenCL C Version: OpenCL C 1.2 
            Device Profile: FULL_PROFILE
            Device Version: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
            Device Extensions: cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_device_uuid cl_khr_pci_bus_info
            Device Max clock frequency (MHz): 1815
            Device Max compute units: 48
            Device Max work group size: 1024

CUDA device capabilities:
    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK           1024
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X         1024
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Y         1024
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Z         64
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_X          2147483647
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_Y          65535
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_Z          65535
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK         49152
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK         49152
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TOTAL_CONSTANT_MEMORY           65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_WARP_SIZE           32
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_PITCH           2147483647
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_REGISTERS_PER_BLOCK         65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_REGISTERS_PER_BLOCK         65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CLOCK_RATE          1815000
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_ALIGNMENT           512
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_GPU_OVERLAP         1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT            48
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_KERNEL_EXEC_TIMEOUT         0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRATED          0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CAN_MAP_HOST_MEMORY         1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_MODE            0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_WIDTH         131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_WIDTH         131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_HEIGHT            65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_WIDTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_HEIGHT            16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_DEPTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_HEIGHT            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_WIDTH           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_HEIGHT          32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_NUMSLICES           2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SURFACE_ALIGNMENT           512
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CONCURRENT_KERNELS          1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_ECC_ENABLED         0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TCC_DRIVER          0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MEMORY_CLOCK_RATE           7751000
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_GLOBAL_MEMORY_BUS_WIDTH         256
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_L2_CACHE_SIZE           4194304
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_THREADS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR          1024
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_ASYNC_ENGINE_COUNT          2
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_UNIFIED_ADDRESSING          1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CAN_TEX2D_GATHER            1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_GATHER_WIDTH          32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_GATHER_HEIGHT         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_WIDTH_ALTERNATE           8192
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_HEIGHT_ALTERNATE          8192
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_DEPTH_ALTERNATE           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_PITCH_ALIGNMENT         32
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_LAYERED_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_LAYERED_LAYERS           2046
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_WIDTH         131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_HEIGHT            65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_WIDTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_HEIGHT            16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_DEPTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_HEIGHT            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_LAYERED_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_LAYERED_LAYERS           2046
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LINEAR_WIDTH          268435456
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_WIDTH          131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_HEIGHT         65000
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_PITCH          2097120
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_MIPMAPPED_WIDTH           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_MIPMAPPED_HEIGHT          32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MAJOR            7
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MINOR            5
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_MIPMAPPED_WIDTH           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_STREAM_PRIORITIES_SUPPORTED         1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_GLOBAL_L1_CACHE_SUPPORTED           1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL_L1_CACHE_SUPPORTED            1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR            65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_REGISTERS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR            65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MANAGED_MEMORY          1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTI_GPU_BOARD         0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTI_GPU_BOARD_GROUP_ID            0


Enabled add-ons:
=====================================

io_anim_bvh (version: (1, 0, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\__init__.py)
io_curve_svg (version: UNKNOWN, path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_curve_svg\__init__.py)
io_mesh_ply (version: UNKNOWN, path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_mesh_ply\__init__.py)
io_mesh_stl (version: (1, 1, 3), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl\__init__.py)
io_mesh_uv_layout (version: (1, 1, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_mesh_uv_layout\__init__.py)
io_scene_fbx (version: (4, 22, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py)
io_scene_gltf2 (version: (1, 6, 16), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py)
io_scene_obj (version: (3, 8, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py)
io_scene_x3d (version: (2, 2, 5), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\__init__.py)
cycles (version: UNKNOWN, path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\addons\cycles\__init__.py)
```
````

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: You can try moving or deleting the folder 'C:\\Users\\eighp\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.93\\' This should return Blender to factory settings. But as Duarte said, we are Blender enthusiasts, not official support.

Comment: sorry about that still new to this.. will write a bug report then. Thank you for the suggestions!